# How to close the control sidebar class on outside click (AdminLTE)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, adminlte

```
<aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
 ......
</aside>
```

I've tried this by adding sidebar-collapse. But it's not working.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are giving too few information. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing us what you tried so far.

Comment: Are you using the entire AdmintLTE or only the aside class?

Comment: Yes @KarthikVenkatraman I'm using entire AdminLTE. But aside with class control-sidebar makes an issue. others working fine.. data toggle is working only when clicking on sidebar. Its not working when click on outside

Comment: Thank you @MarioCianciolo.. I've used the aside like     <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        <div class="box-body extn-fl">
</div> </aside> ...In html used a data-toggle of control sidebar. Its working correctly. When click on outside, unable to close the sidebar.

Comment: @Anitha, Outside means where? inside your page in any area other than the aside class?

Comment: Any area other than the aside class within the page.. @KarthikVenkatraman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle the aside using jquery. Since you have used the AdminLTE, it has inbuilt operations for side bar toggle. Check the jQuery and app.min.js references. May be its not working due to invalid file references.

Below is another method using the toggle function.

```js
var master = $('[data-name="master"]'),
  side = $('[data-name="side"]');

$('.toggle', master).on('click', function() {
  master.toggleClass('slide');
  side.toggleClass('pop');
});
```

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  font: normal 14px/1.4em Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin-top: .5em;
}

[role="main"] {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  background: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1)
}

[data-name="side"] {
  position: absolute;
  width: 14.28571428571429em;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 1em;
  background: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

[data-name="side"] ul {
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(.8, .8);
}

[data-name="side"].pop ul {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
}

[data-name="side"] li {
  color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  padding: .5em .5em .6em .5em;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}

[data-name="side"] li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

[data-name="side"] li:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

[data-name="master"] {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1em;
  height: inherit;
  background: inherit;
  box-shadow: -1px 0 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}

[data-name="master"].slide {
  left: 14.28571428571429em;
}

[data-name="master"].slide .toggle {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1.2em);
}

.toggle {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  -webkit-transition: all 100ms 200ms;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-15px);
}

.toggle:before {
  position: relative;
  content: '\2630';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<div role="main">
  <aside data-name="side">
    <ul>
      <li>Menu Item</li>
      <li>Additional</li>
      <li>Here's Another</li>
      <li>More Here</li>
      <li>One Final</li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <section data-name="master">
    <div class="toggle"></div>
    <p>AdminLTE is a popular open source WebApp template for admin dashboards and control panels. It is a responsive HTML template that is based on the CSS framework Bootstrap 3. It utilizes all of the Bootstrap components in its design and re-styles many
      commonly used plugins to create a consistent design that can be used as a user interface for backend applications. AdminLTE is based on a modular design, which allows it to be easily customized and built upon. This documentation will guide you through
      installing the template and exploring the various components that are bundled with the template.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Use the below code

```
$('div').click(function(e) {
   master.toggleClass('slide');
  side.toggleClass('pop');
})
```

U can change the div to any element you want.

Comment: Thank you @Karthik.. Let me try this.

Comment: Its not working :(.. Here the sidebar only closes on clicking on the menu icon. Unable to close when clicking on other areas.

Comment: Have updated the javascript under update. This will hide the toggle button. jsfiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/karthik82vk/hoecys41/3/

Comment: Let me know if it works. Also please upvote and mark the answer f it had solved your request so that it will be helpful for others who has same issues.

Comment: Thank you @Karthik. Have I need to use data-name in aside?  Is it possible to with control-sidebar in class of aside? In my case, I'm using control-sidebar and control-sidebar-dark in aside and here data-toggle is working well. but this is not closing when clicking any other area. Shall I try to use data-name in aside like above??

Comment: You can try. data-name and class are different objects and you can have both the things in same aside tag. You need to modify the css value of the class "control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark" such as position, left, etc as it will overide the values in the css i have  provided. You can also overide the default values of the control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark css using the !important tag in my css.

Answer (score 2):

```
       <aside id="cust_sidebar" class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
        ......
      </aside>




    <script>
        $('.content-wrapper').click(function (e) {
            var get_class = $("#cust_sidebar").attr('class');       
            console.log(get_mini);
            if (get_class == "control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark control-sidebar-open") {
                $('#cust_sidebar').removeClass('control-sidebar-open');
            }               
        })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

A further simplification of @Charlie 's answer that doesn't break if you theme (skin) the control sidebar:

html

```
<aside id="control_sidebar" class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    ......
</aside>
```

js (jquery)

```
    $(".content-wrapper").click(function() {
        if ($("#control_sidebar").hasClass("control-sidebar-open")) {
            $("#control_sidebar").removeClass("control-sidebar-open");
        }
    });
```

Comment: I liked this option for react project. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i faced same problem..
solved by :

```
$(".content-wrapper").click(function() {
    //console.log('test click');
    $("#control_sidebar").ControlSidebar('collapse');
    
});

<aside id="control_sidebar" class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-light" ....

</aside>
```